# How to save files to a foreign key model in django

Tags: django, django-models

I am using a django model to save user uploaded images. I want each image to be stored in the productimage model that is a foreign key model to the product model which is a foreign key model to the user model. What I mean is:

User -----> Product ------> Productimage

I want to create a new instance of the productimage model but can't seem to figure out how to since it is a foreign key to another foreign key.
I do not know how to target a foreign key within a foreign key to create. For example I've tried:

request.user.product.productimage.create()

request.user.product_set.productimage_set.create()

request.user.product.productimage_set.create()

Nothing seems to create a new instance of the productimage model.

```
class product(models.Model):
 user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 product_title =  models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
 product_price =  models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
 product_description =  models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True)

class productimage(models.Model):
product = models.ForeignKey(product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
product_images = models.FileField(blank=True)


def add(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    product_title = request.POST.get("product_title")
    product_price = request.POST.get("product_price")
    product_description = request.POST.get("product_description")
    request.user.product_set.create(product_title = product_title,product_price =product_price, product_description = product_description,)
    for file in request.FILES.getlist("filepond"):
        product_images = file
        request.user.product_set.productimage_set.create()###trying to create a new instance of productimage model for each file
return render(request,"main/add.html")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already created your product just a few lines earlier; you just have to use that.

```
product = request.user.product_set.create(product_title = product_title,product_price =product_price, product_description = product_description,)
for file in request.FILES.getlist("filepond"):
    product_images = file
    product.productimage_set.create()
```